# Configure Email in JBoss - JNDI Resouce not getting correct configuration

Tags: java, email, jboss

I am trying to configure my application to send emails in JBoss 7.10.GA.  Everything looks to be configured properly but when I test my code it throw an error:

javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: localhost, port: 25;

It appears that it is not finding the correct email configuration in my standalone.xml file because it just defaults to localhost port 25.  From all the forms I have read this is all the configuration that needs to be done but I must be missing something.

```
  <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:mail:1.1">
        <mail-session jndi-name="java:jboss/mail/Gmail">
            <smtp-server ssl="true" outbound-socket-binding-ref="mail-gmail-smtp">
                <login name="email@gmail.com" password="password"/>
            </smtp-server>
        </mail-session>
    </subsystem>
  <socket-binding-group...
      <outbound-socket-binding name="mail-gmail-smtp">
          <remote-destination host="smtp.gmail.com" port="465"/>
      </outbound-socket-binding>
  </socket-binding-group>
```

and I have this in my class:

```
import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.mail.Address;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;

public class SendEmail extends HttpServlet {       
    @Resource(lookup = "java:jboss/mail/Gmail")
    private Session mailSession;

    public SendEmail() {
        try {
            MimeMessage m = new MimeMessage(mailSession);
            Address from = new InternetAddress("email@gmail.com");
            Address[] to = new InternetAddress[] { new InternetAddress(
                "email@gmail.com") };
            m.setFrom(from);
            m.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, to);
            m.setSubject("Google JavaMail Test");
            m.setContent("Test from inside JBoss AS7 Server", "text/plain");
            Transport.send(m);           
        } catch (javax.mail.MessagingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: is appears that @Resource(lookup = "java:jboss/mail/Gmail") is not finding the resource

Comment: Does it show up on the startup logs?

Comment: Nothing is shown in the startup log.

Comment: What about the Default one, is it showing up on the server.log? Just wanted make sure that your startup script is using right config xml file.

Comment: The log should have something like `Bound mail session [java:jboss/mail/Default]`, both for the default one and the gmail one.

Comment: Sorry I found it  [org.jboss.as.mail.extension] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015400: Bound mail session [java:jboss/mail/Gmail]

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to make it work locally but not when deployed to OpenShift, it was due to the resource name not being found.

I removed:

```
@Resource(lookup = "java:jboss/mail/Gmail")
```

and added:

```
InitialContext ic = new InitialContext();       
mailSession = (Session)ic.lookup("java:jboss/mail/Gmail");
```

This is the article I referenced

https://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-13836

Update:
Sending email works on my local configuration but when I deploy it to OpenShift I get the following error:

javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [jboss/mail/Gmail] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [jboss].

I assume this is because it's setup on my local copy and didn't transfer to OpenShift.  Now I need to find out what file I need to add these declarations to in the .openshift/config directory. Anyone know?

Comment: So does this work regardless of any port you specify?

Comment: I didn't try a different port but it worked for me on port 465